# A BVP question using green's function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When doing exercise, I found this question with boundary conditions I couldn't solve.

$y′′ + y = f(x)$, $ \ $ $0 < x < 2\pi$, $ \ $ $y(0) − y(2\pi) = 0$, $ \ $ $y′(0) − y′(2\pi) = 0$

The question is asking what goes wrong in this problem?

I know solving auxilary equation gives $y=Asin(x)+Bcos(x)$.
It seems that at values of $sin(0)=sin(2\pi),cos(0)=cos(2\pi)$.

So I couldn't find out $A$ and $B$ when I split the solution to linearly independent $y=Asin(x)$ $(x<x')$ and $y=Bcos(x)$ $(x>x')$.

I wonder if this is the case, or there is something else going wrong?

Comment: Your solution sounds correct to me. The boundary conditions don't give you any extra information as they are always true for $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Although *all* solutions of $y''+y=0$ are $2\pi-$periodic, this is **not** necessarily true of the *inhomogeneous* problem $y''+y=f(x)$. For that problem, you'll need to apply the variation of constants/parameters formula:
$$
y(x) = \left[C_+ - y_+(x) \int_0^x \frac{f(s) y_-(s)}{W(s)} ds \right] + \left[C_- + y_-(x) \int_0^x \frac{f(s) y_+(s)}{W(s)} ds \right] .
$$
Here, $y_\pm$ are two fundamental solutions (e.g., the cosine/sine you already use) and $W$ is the Wronskian:
$$
W(x) = \det\left[\begin{array}{cc}y_+(x) & y_-(x) \\ y'_+(x) & y'_-(x)\end{array}\right] .
$$
(In your case, it should turn out *constant* because there's no 1st order term.)

Now apply the BCs to find $C_\pm$ & good luck.

**EDIT** Since you're asking '*what goes wrong,*' you should first recognize that periodic BCs yield periodic solutions - because of the ODE (relating the second derivative to the first and zeroth ones, and thus also the third, fourth & so on), you get periodicity for *all* derivatives. Nevertheless, whether there are any periodic solutions depends, here, on whether the forcing $f$ adds to or subtracts energy from the system. Since $C_\pm$ do not control $f$, they *cannot* be selected in a way ensuring a periodic solution. That's the intuitive picture; filling in the details is up to you.